# How to move an object without it completely teleporting somewhere else?

Tags: transforms

Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/VltFR7ytxVg)

I move almost any object in blender up/down, left/right, it immediately breaks and goes past another object. If I use the bottom left menus that show up when you move/scale/rotate, they move fine without breaking. Whenever using the direct arrows, they just break. How do I fix that? It would make the projects I'm doing so much easier if I didn't have to redo their positioning every 20 seconds I decide to slightly move something.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the video, it looks like you are constantly pressing the middle mouse button while moving the cylinder. Constantly pressing the middle mouse button and moving the mouse switches the axis and moves the object on that axis. This happens again and again which causes the teleportation effect.

You can fix this by:

1. Releasing the middle mouse button after selecting the required axis.
2. Instead of using middle mouse button, using X,Y,Z on keyboard to lock the axis.

Comment: That's interesting as I'm not touching the middle mouse button at all, I decided to try and move while holding the middle mouse button and that made the axis constantly change while moving. Should I try a different mouse?

Comment: Switched the mouse, same thing happened. Here's a better video displaying what happens. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05WigktJrw4

Comment: Can you provide the blend file? Just upload it to https://pasteall.org/blend/  and share the link

Answer (score 0):

you can do
<kbd>G</kbd>-Move around
<kbd>R</kbd>-Rotate
<kbd>S</kbd>-Scaling

---

now after pressing any of these buttons, you can press
<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd> to make the action along this particular axis

or you can do,
<kbd>Shift+X</kbd> - to make action along Y and Z axis
<kbd>Shift+Y</kbd> - to make action along X and Z axis
<kbd>Shift+Z</kbd> - to make action along X and Y axis